# how to get visitor browser window size in perl CGI

Tags: javascript, html, perl, web

Does anyone know how to get the height and width of user's browser window in a Perl CGI script?

Or how can i pass this value to my $var from javascript or other languages ???

Comment: @Amberlamps: and it might be wasted by generating some garbage and sending it to server

Comment: If the OP only wants browser sizes for statistics then Google Analytics would probably be a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about a perl script that gets called via a form and then prints a web site, you can use javascript to get the browser size, put it into hidden form variables and retrieve them with [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/) in your perl script. It can then react to the values, e.g. change the size of a static piece of web layout.

On the web site, use javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms[0].windowheight.value = window.innerHeight;
document.forms[0].windowwidth.value = window.innerWidth;
</script>
```

But keep in mind that different browsers use different ways in JS to get the size values. Maybe [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) helps. You could also use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to determine these values.

When you have them in your `<form>` and submit it, you can use the `CGI` module to read them just the same as all the other form parameters. It doesn't matter if they were sent via POST or GET.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $windowHeight = $cgi->param('windowheight');
my $windowWidth = $cgi->param('windowwidth');
```