# how to assign javascript values to Perl variables

Tags: javascript, html, perl

i have this javascript function:

```
print <<"EOT";
<script type="text/javascript">
 function alertSize() {
  var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
    window.alert( 'Width = ' + myWidth );
    window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
}
</script>
EOT
print "<body onload='alertSize()'>";
print "</body>";

my $windowHeight = $q->param('myHeight');
my $windowWidth = $q->param('windowwidth');
print "<$windowHeight><$windowWidth>";
```

How to pass the values of  and  from javascript function to my Perl variables ?

Comment: You already asked almost the same question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480705/how-to-get-visitor-browser-window-size-in-perl-cgi - try to be more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Perl is running on the server. It outputs some text which is sent to the client (the browser).

The browser then interprets that text and HTML and JavaScript.

You can't pass data back to Perl without making a new HTTP request.

Your options include:

- Finish the processing with JavaScript instead of trying to pass it back to Perl
- Use Ajax to make a new HTTP request
- Set `location.href` to load a new page with the data passed in the query string
- Find a way to achieve your (unspecified) goal without using your current logic (e.g. you could use CSS media queries to style a page differently based on browser dimensions).

Comment: i will use that values to sendit to the css file to calculate the <div> height

Comment: Make use of percentages or media queries instead.